# ServiceStack - Attribute knows what class it is calling from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

Say, I have a LogAttribute class like this:

```
  public class LogAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, 
                                 IHttpResponse res, 
                                 object dto) { /*...*/ }
  }    
  [Log]
  public class TransportService : Service { /*...*/ }
  [Log]
  public class HealthService : Service { /*...*/ }
```

How does the LogAttribute class know what class it is calling from? Namely, TransportService or HealthService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Request DTO that's passed in as well as the metadata ServiceStack maintains about your service, e.g:

```
var serviceType = HostContext.Metadata.GetServiceTypeByRequest(dto.GetType());
```